# IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword

Tags: clojure

Why does this:

```
(-> xs
    (map :foo))
```

, result in the following error message:

> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect threading macro. You really meant to use `->>`.

My real problem was that the error message seemed so foreign. However the message "Don't know how to create ISeq from ..." makes sense when you know that map, filter etc. work by going first/rest through the input. If the input is not an ISeq they try to create an ISeq from it - hence the error message.